# can i write a google drive text editor in js without a middle hand server?

Tags: google-drive-api

Cant find any examples of it, but it seems like a roundabout (and security cost) to need a middle hand?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely possible to write a client-side only JavaScript app that interacts with Google Drive. Check the Google Drive SDK documentation for a quickstart guide showing how to build your first JavaScript Drive app:

https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-js